# Haskell: "No instance for (Fractional (Maybe Float)) arising from the literal '0.0'"

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a function that given a specific condition will add either 0.0 or Nothing to the end of a list however the compiler won't accept me simply adding the literal number to the list and returns the error quoted in the title.

Here is the code that's returning the error

```
createDistList :: WAdjList -> Int -> Int -> [Maybe Float] -> [Maybe Float]
createDistList [] i j ys = if i == j then ys ++ [0.0] else ys ++ [Nothing]
```

The code is extended past this but it's the same error happening again in the same context.

Comment: for sure you need modify the `then` part with `ys ++ [Just 0.0]`, but the error you have is different, what's the definition of `WadjList`?

Comment: `Nothing` is not a special value that can belong to *any* type. `0.0` and `Nothing` cannot appear in the same list. Or more precisely (since you did provide a type for your function), `0.0` is not a value of type `Maybe Float`; `Just 0.0` is.

Comment: Actually that solved the problem entirely, or at least stopped the errors from appearing on compilation. I can't believe I forgot that, this is what I get for working while super tired I guess. Thanks a lot though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `ys` has type `[Maybe Float]`, not `Float`. You might expect an error telling you that `0.0` doesn't have type `Maybe Float`. But it's more complicated than that, because `0.0` itself doesn't have type `Float`; it has type `Fractional a => a`.

Because type classes are open, the type checker is willing to believe that maybe `0.0` *can* provide a value of type `Maybe Float`. But for that to happen, you need to define a `Fractional` instance for `Maybe Float`. You haven't, which is what the error message is telling you.

The solution is to provide the correct value in your function: use `Just 0.0`, not `0.0`.

```
createDistList :: WAdjList -> Int -> Int -> [Maybe Float] -> [Maybe Float]
createDistList [] i j ys = if i == j then ys ++ [Just 0.0] else ys ++ [Nothing]
```

or more briefly,

```
createDistList :: WAdjList -> Int -> Int -> [Maybe Float] -> [Maybe Float]
createDistList [] i j ys = ys ++ [if i == j then Just 0.0 else Nothing]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I feel silly seeing that I forgot the Just but I guess this just happens sometimes. I appreciate the answer!